# HTML - CSS: cross-browser semi-transparency

Tags: html, css

I've to make the background of my fading-in menu items semi-transparent.

It has to be grey but still I need to see what's below it.

What's an easy *cross-browser* solution for semi-transparency ? (Possibly without using images)

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
selector {
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* internet explorer /
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;      / khtml, old safari /
    -moz-opacity: 0.5;       / mozilla, netscape /
    opacity: 0.5;           / fx, safari, opera */
}
```

http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/01/27/cross-browser-transparency-via-css/

Comment: You no longer need `-moz-opacity` or `-khtml-opacity` unless you need to cater for very old versions of Firefox/Safari. They both support plain `opacity` now (and have done for some time). Konqueror never used `-khtml-opacity`.

Answer (score 5):

**CSS Transparency Settings for All Browsers**
http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/